# Style Table Columns at different widths using CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, web-applications

I need to set the middle column to 100%. The css works appropriately below unless I change a column width to 100% then it removes all the widths for the other columns. Anyone know why?

```
.SummaryTable td:first-child
{
    width: 150px;
}
.SummaryTable td:first-child + td
{
    width: 150px; /*100% will remove other col widths*/
}
.SummaryTable td:first-child + td + td
{
    width: 175%;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qw2fZ/2/)

Comment: you should have added a fiddle.

Comment: Setting the middle one to 100% means it takes the whole space - what space do you have left for other cells? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The table width is set to 100% to fill Div. Then I want columns 1 and 3 to be fixed while the 2nd one fills the remaining area. I just answered my own question. I removed the width style from the 2nd column and now it works fine.

Comment: Note: When i set the middle column to 100% the first and last column widths would size to the contents of the cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not setting the width for the middle cell should fix it for you provided the table has width=100%.

The other cells would be fixed but the cells that do not have width specified would fill the screen.

Try this, I think it should work

```
.SummaryTable td:first-child
{
    width: 150px;
}
.SummaryTable td:first-child + td
{
   /* don't set any width for the middle cell, it would expand */
}
.SummaryTable td:first-child + td + td
{
    width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the total table a specific width:

```
.SummaryTable {width: 100%}
```

Then remove the width from the second column, resulting in it to fill the remaining width the first and third have left from the total width.

Answer (score 0):

if i were you i wouldnt use css `:child`, it wont work on old versions of IE. (IE8,IE7..).

you better use jquery for that, you could try:

`$('.SummaryTable td:nth-child(2)').css({width: '100%'})`

or you could use `:eq`:

`$('.SummaryTable td:eq(1)').css({width: '100%'})`

note that when you use `:eq` the counter starts by 0, so 1 is the 2nd position.